# Iframe в родительском окне

Tags: javascript

Я загружаю на страницу Iframe с другого домена, соответственно при использовании window.parent у меня выдаёт ошибку (домены не совпадают и т.д.). Как в родительском окне доступиться до iframe с другого домена?

PS: Я загружаю свой же Iframe на другой сайт, соответственно я могу менять и код в iframe при необходимости.

Comment: Другой домен не является поддоменном основного?

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, то:
  фрейм.document
например:

```
frame1 = document.getElementById("frame1"); //фрейм с id = "frame1";
frame1.document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#000000";
```

Comment: как-то так, но оно не будет работать если домены разные, это специально сделали защиту против [межсайтового скриптинга][1]


  [1]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B6%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3

Answer (score 0):

Для mozilla/fiefox мне помогало вот это: [Signed Scripts in Mozilla](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/components/signed-scripts.html). Но это пользователь должен сам у себя разрешить.